# The making of an actual batch anti virus

Tags: batch-file, antivirus

I want to make an anti-virus in batch, i know it can be done. The anti virus is going to be based on md5 hashes.

Im asking for a little help with this:

I have a **database.txt** with some **md5 hashes** of viruses, I need to "**compare**" it to a **scannedfiles.txt** It should now **auto delete** this files found.

I know it all sounds very confusing, but at the same time i have never seen an anti virus made in batch.

here is how the scannedfiles.txt look like:

```
ac20a4ed0c586b32e80f2156188cd1a2 c:\boot\bg-BG\bootmgr.exe.mui
4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a237fe6c8 c:\boot\cs-CZ\bootmgr.exe.mui
0eac4b3cf928be35e0f73cfe3e43047c c:\boot\cs-CZ\memtest.exe.mui
```

Here is a download for the files, then you can work with them.
https://mega.co.nz/#!ws8XHQyT!2NK5c2IgiO9jXM2AYDjkP-wzsi5Ub_kq7k56XIBYeFQ

Comment: Is batch your primary choice? Because I would recommend you doing this with python, since there are a lot of code available.

Comment: I want to use batch for this, i know, it will be very complicated to do, if vbs is needed then sure, use it.

Comment: @SonerGönül and the rest of users that closed this topic. In my opinion, the request is very clear and simple: compare two text files and delete filenames that appear in both...

Comment: I will recommend you to use SHA256. I have a similar project where I'm making manually a SHA256 database. [Project and database link](https://github.com/anic17/Batch-Antivirus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch file below "compare scannedfiles.txt vs. database.txt and auto delete the files in the scannedfiles.txt that are also in the database":

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /G:database.txt scannedfiles.txt') do del "%%a"
```

**EDIT**: *Output example added*

```
C:\test> type test.bat
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /G:database.txt scannedfiles.txt') do echo %%a

C:\test> type database.txt
4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a237fe6c8
ABC4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a23XYZ

C:\test> type scannedfiles.txt
ac20a4ed0c586b32e80f2156188cd1a2 c:\boot\bg-BG\bootmgr.exe.mui
4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a237fe6c8 c:\boot\cs-CZ\bootmgr.exe.mui
0eac4b3cf928be35e0f73cfe3e43047c c:\boot\cs-CZ\memtest.exe.mui

C:\test> test.bat
c:\boot\cs-CZ\bootmgr.exe.mui

C:\test> echo ABC4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a23XYZ C:\BOOT\XYZ\fciv.exe>> scannedfiles.txt

C:\test> type scannedfiles.txt
ac20a4ed0c586b32e80f2156188cd1a2 c:\boot\bg-BG\bootmgr.exe.mui
4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a237fe6c8 c:\boot\cs-CZ\bootmgr.exe.mui
0eac4b3cf928be35e0f73cfe3e43047c c:\boot\cs-CZ\memtest.exe.mui
ABC4dae40edfa2cc6c4f631f30a23XYZ C:\BOOT\XYZ\fciv.exe

C:\test> test.bat
c:\boot\cs-CZ\bootmgr.exe.mui
C:\BOOT\XYZ\fciv.exe
```